# Show/Hide div depend on dropdown select in AngularJS with default value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-select

I am new to Angularjs. I have tired show & hide div using dropdown select and it is working. But I don't have idea to show the default values.

**Requirement :** Initial stage I have to display the first option in the dropdown and show the respective div

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <select name="name" ng-model="region.name" ng-dropdown required ng-change="changeme()"
     <option ng-option value="us" selected="selected">us</option>
     <option ng-option value="uk">uk</option>
   </select>
  <div id="one" ng-if="region.name == 'us'"> US based event</div>
  <div id="two" ng-if="region.name == 'uk'"> UK based event</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window, $element) {
  $scope.changeme = function() {
        //no code
  }

});
```

Ref code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vL4pt5pL/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set default values, simply assign them in your controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window, $element) {
  $scope.region.name = 'uk';

});
```

See updated jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vL4pt5pL/1/).

To answer your section question, the reason why it's not working is because you haven't actually initialed the object anywhere. When your code attempts to access `region.name`, `region` has not yes been defined, and causes the ng-if statement to no longer attempt to validate. To solve this, initialize the full object at the start:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window, $element) {
  $scope.region = {
    name: 'us'
  };
});
```

See updated jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vL4pt5pL/2/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I have to display the corresponding div also.

Comment: Thank you, it's working. Can we have the name value as dynamic ?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a scope variable into a select, it looks for the options that it contains.

On your code, $scope.region.name is empty or undefined, thus it doesn't match any of your defined options.

You can set the default value on your controller for ex:

```
$scope.region.name = "us"
```

The select now knows what is selected on load.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Here I have to display the corresponding div also. And the region value (us) is dynamic.